# How to read Complex XML Response using C#

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I want to read Bank of Canada XML response to get the closing rates of each currency. 
But they have very complex XML Response, you can check at

Visit www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/closing/en_all.xml

I'm trying my old way for parsing XML but that work's fine only with simple XML i.e

```
  var url ="http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/closing/en_all.xml";
        var uploadResult = CurrencyAPI.TriggerApiAction(url);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(CurrencyAPI.backstr);



        foreach (var download in xDoc.Descendants("cb:exchangeRate"))
        {
            a1 = download.Element("cb:value").Value;
            a2 = download.Element("cb:baseCurrency").Value;
            a3 = download.Element("cb:targetCurrency").Value;
        }
```

Please help me with this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
XNamespace cb = "http://www.cbwiki.net/wiki/index.php/Specification_1.1";
foreach (var download in xDoc.Descendants(cb+"exchangeRate"))
{
    var a1 = download.Element(cb+"value").Value;
    var a2 = download.Element(cb+"baseCurrency").Value;
    var a3 = download.Element(cb+"targetCurrency").Value;
}
```

Or better:

```
XNamespace cb = "http://www.cbwiki.net/wiki/index.php/Specification_1.1";
foreach (var download in xDoc.Descendants(cb+"exchangeRate"))
{
    var a1 = (decimal)download.Element(cb+"value");
    var a2 = (string)download.Element(cb+"baseCurrency");
    var a3 = (string)download.Element(cb+"targetCurrency");
}
```